# subListString Index out of bounds

Tags: java, string, sublist

```
    horse1ProgressionStr = Integer.toString(horse1Progression);
    horse2ProgressionStr = Integer.toString(horse2Progression);
    horse3ProgressionStr = Integer.toString(horse3Progression);
    horse4ProgressionStr = Integer.toString(horse4Progression);




    List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(horse1ProgressionStr, horse2ProgressionStr, horse3ProgressionStr, horse4ProgressionStr));
    for (List<String> l : list) {
        Collections.sort(l);
    }
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
        public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
            return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
        }
    });


    System.out.println("" + list);


    List<List<String>> fourthHorse = list.subList(0, 2);
    List<List<String>> thirdHorse = list.subList(2, 4);
    List<List<String>> secondHorse = list.subList(4, 6);
```

I have been trying to put 4 ints in order and them put them into separate variables but every way i try it seems to give me a out of bounds exception.

Exception =

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 2

Comment: You have exactly **one** `List` inside your `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question is overly complicated, just do this:

```
int[] horses = { horse1Progression, horse2Progression,
                 horse3Progression, horse4Progression };

// sort the input array in ascending order
Arrays.sort(horses);

// retrieve the elements in each position
int first  = horses[0];
int second = horses[1];
int third  = horses[2];
int fourth = horses[3];
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've been trying to do it for ages!

Comment: @user3254808 you're welcome! if this answer solved your problem, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to the left ;)

Answer (score 0):

The size of the object `list` is 4 but you are trying to retrieve the list upto 6 index `list.subList(4, 6)`.